# Profile2_path form_alter - Anonymous user form - access denied problem

Tags: users, uri

I have created a custom profile type and given it a unique registration path using [profile2 registration path](http://drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath). I am attempting to form alter the custom fields but I cant seem to find a way to view the from as admin in order to view the form array.

Whenever I go to the custom path of offers/register as admin I get an 'access denied'. How can I view this form that is for anonymous users whilst logged in as admin so that I can kpr($form);?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set [devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) permissions of 'Access developer information' to anonymous user . 
Make sure to disable this module on a production site.